# How to convert ArrayList<String> to Array <String> in kotlin?

Tags: arrays, kotlin, arraylist, type-conversion

I have the code:

```kotlin
    val al:ArrayList<String> =ArrayList<String>()
    al.add("123")
    val arr=al.toArray()
    println((arr as Array<String>).javaClass.kotlin.qualifiedName)
```

I want convert `al` to `String[]`,but I will get the error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object[] cannot be cast to java.lang.String[]
```

how can I do?

Comment: Use `toTypedArray()`

Answer (score 0):

Just as @Tenfour04 commented on the first floor, I tried `toTypedArray()`:

```kotlin
val al:ArrayList<String> =ArrayList<String>()
al.add("123")
println((al.toTypedArray()).javaClass.kotlin.qualifiedName)
```

Solved my error now, it successfully converted!